# Cassandra update query to append data to existing value in a column

Tags: cassandra, cql

Can you please provide the query to append data to an existing value in a column of type text? Something similar to this:

```
 UPDATE cycling.upcoming_calendar SET events = events + ['Tour de France Stage 10'] WHERE year = 2015 AND month = 06;
```

The above query will update a list. My column datatype is text. 
In my case, if the column `"events"` has a value, `"Test"` I want to update it to the value, `"Test , Test1"`.

Comment: Not possible, you can only update lists in such mannner

Comment: If you really want to do it this way, I suggest you query your text column value first, then append to it, then write it back. Otherwise you can use a list or a set and try to achieve what you want using them.

Answer (score 2):

Appending data to a text column is not possible in Cassandra. The only possible options I can think of are

Option 1 : Change the column data type to List

Option 2 : Fetch the data from the column in your application and then append the new value to the existing value, and finally update the DB.